# well water pressure coming and going

Tags: water

What could the cause of our well water coming and going.  We can use the water and it will work fine then the pressure will start to go until we have no water at all.  We wait a couple hours or so and it starts working again.  Then ocassionly the problem will continue this cycle other times it works fine after that.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Is this a deep or shallow well? Can you tell if the pump is running when the pressure is low? Do you know what the water level is? Is there a pressure gauge on the pressure tank, and if so what does it read when there's a problem? (Summary: we need more details.)

Comment: Only thing I can add is that it is a deep well and that it is a submersible pump.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Could be your water level is too low, could be your pump failing, could be a problem with the pressure switch. Can't tell without more information.

Comment: Thanks.  I guess we will have someone out to look at it.  We have been told before that we have plenty of water in the well but I could not say that for sure.  In the 16 years I have been here we have had to have the pump replaced twice.  We do also have a lot minerals and hard water.  Not sure if any of that means anything or not.  Thanks for your timely response and help.

Comment: Do you get any air in the pipes when it isn't working? Can you watch the pressure gauge on the system (usually by the pressure tank) and see when the pump turns on and when it turns off?

Answer (score 1):

Usually the symptoms you describe here:

> the pressure will start to go until we have no water at all. We wait a couple hours or so and it starts working again.

Mean that the recharge rate (inflow of water from the ground to your well) are insufficient to keep up with your use. This can be compounded if the overall water level in the well varies since the water in the well above the pump serves as a store of water that can be pumped out, without needing to be immediately replenished. If the overall water level drops that will reduce your storage above the pump, and often also reduce your recharge rate.

There are a variety of techniques and technologies that can be applied, many expensive, a few less so, and they depend on the specifics of your well and pump installation. If you happen to have a well that is much deeper than your pump placement, you can sometimes lower the pump - but that's a fairly rare situation. Hydrofracture uses high-pressure water to attempt to increase the recharge rate by cracking the rock at the bottom of the well. Drilling the well deeper is a fairly simple approach, but pretty expensive since it requires a drill rig and assembling the entire drill rod to get down to the bottom of the existing well, and then drilling it deeper. Depending on your local strata, that approach can backfire.

One relatively easy place to start is to deal with any leaks or excessive water use by changing fixtures, so as to reduce your water use and thus the demand on the well. If you have an old-fashioned toilet that uses 3 or more gallons per flush, replacing it with a modern 1.25 gallon per flush (unless they have gotten even lower) unit might save a lot of water, so long as it's a quality unit that does not take 3 flushes to clear. If you already have 1.6 GPF toilets that's not such a big difference. Water softeners also vary quite a bit in how much water they use for recharging.

Answer (score 0):

Having the pump replaced 2X in 16 years and now a 3rd time sounds like a problem to me. It is possible the high mineral content is loading up the pump and causing it to overheat (thermal overload trips and needs to cool down) an inexpensive amp clamp meter can be used to see if the pump is actually trying to run when there is no water being pumped. I use a fluke T5-600 these can be found on line for <100$ and there are less expensive units out there. The pressure switch could be failing as another possible issue but the timing would point to the pump or recharge rate that @Ecnerwal points to. To test with an amp clamp all you need to do is put the meter on 1 of the hot leads to the pump nothing needs to be disconnected if the pump is trying to run there will be a current draw. depending on the size of the pump 1/2 hp up to 3hp for example we could tell if the overload is tripped no current, close to full load or higher amperage pump stalled, much less than full load no water to pump.
I doubt if it has starting capacitors that they are the problem because it restarts.